# Infinite scroll works in Chrome, breaks in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, angularjs-directive, infinite-scroll

I have a directive that gets placed inside a details page, and displays a table of server side data, one fresh batch at a time. Right now it's working as expected in Chrome -- whenever the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, the loadResults() function gets called, and it loads some more. However, I get none of that behavior in Firefox, and I'm thinking it has something to do with what parts of $window and $document are made available, but I'm not sure which. Appreciate any help in advance.

Here's the relevant directive code:

```
function drContainerContentsDirective($window, $document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope) {
      angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function() {
        var windowBottom = $document[0].body.scrollTop + $window.innerHeight;
        if(windowBottom >= $document[0].body.scrollHeight) {
          scope.$apply(scope.loadResults);
        } 
      });
    },
    controller: drContainerContentsController,
    templateUrl: 'js/directive/drContainerContent/drContainerContents.tpl.html',
    scope: {
      contentParentType: '@type'
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, at least till the next thing breaks -- I used  `$window.pageYOffset` in place of `$document[0].body.scrollTop` and that works in both browsers (haven't tried IE yet).

**EDIT**

Works in IE too